# Sort by multiple fields in ElasticSearch C#

Tags: c#, elasticsearch

I want to sort my response by `rank_tx` Desc followed by `_score` Desc.
Currently, I can do by `rank_tx` or `_score` only.

.csproj

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

    <PropertyGroup>
        <TargetFramework>net7.0</TargetFramework>
    .........
    </PropertyGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
        <PackageReference Include="Elastic.Clients.Elasticsearch" Version="8.9.1" /
    ........
```

C# code

```
var response = await _client.SearchAsync<Model>(search =>
{
    search.Index(_indexOptions.Index)
         .Query(q => q
            .Bool(b => b
                .Should(
                    sh => sh.MatchPhrasePrefix(m => m.Field(f => f.field1).Query(input)),
                    sh => sh.MatchPhrase(m => m.Field(f => f.field1).Query(input).Slop(50))
                )
            )
         )
        .Size(50)
        .Sort(s => s
             .Field(Infer.Field<Model>(f => f.rank_tx), fs => fs.Order(SortOrder.Desc)))
        .Highlight(highlightOptions);
}, cancellationToken);
```

This work's fine on Console.

```
GET /my_index/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "match_phrase_prefix": {
            "my_field_1": {
              "query": input
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "match_phrase": {
            "my_field_2": {
              "query": input,
              "slop": 50
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "sort": [
    { "rank_tx": { "order": "desc" } },
    { "_score": { "order": "desc" } }
  ],
  "size": 50
}
```

I have gone through official documentation, couldn't get the solution.

These fixes didn't work:-

1. Added two sort fields in sort

```
 .Sort(s => s
      .Field(Infer.Field<Model>(f => f.rank_tx), fs => fs.Order(SortOrder.Desc))
      .Field("_score", fs => fs.Order(SortOrder.Desc)))
```

2. Used SortOptionsDescriptor

```
var sortFields = new SortOptionsDescriptor<Model>()
            .Field(Infer.Field<Model>(f => f.rank_tx), fs => fs.Order(SortOrder.Desc))
            .Field("_score", fs => fs.Order(SortOrder.Desc));

.Sort(sortFields)
```

On both, I got response sorted by `_score`, which means It considers last field only.

Comment: Script score or function score query can help.

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-script-score-query.html

Comment: @MusabDogan I have read Script score and function score query. Could you please show how to implement ?

Comment: Check this one https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/7.16/script-score-query-usage.html

Comment: @MusabDogan Thank you for the help with resources, but I don't have much experience in Elastic Search.
If you have some free time, please post the solution for it. I have gone through your recommended references but couldn't able to solve it.

Comment: You're welcome. Sorry, I can't share the exact solution for your specific scenario. You need to dig into it, maybe chatGPT can help.

Comment: Am I doing something non-trivial here? are multiple fields sorting in elastic search c# non-popular? I have tried Chatgpt and Bing Chat Enterprise, it gives the first fix that I mentioned which didn't work.

Comment: @MusabDogan Thanks for the help, I have posted the solution. Please do checkout.

Comment: Happy to hear it fixed. And thanks for let me know :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Issue

In both fixes, I was reconfiguring the same `SortOptionsDescriptor`, that's why only the final call applies to the final object.

```
.Sort(s => s
      .Field(Infer.Field<Model>(f => f.rank_tx), fs => fs.Order(SortOrder.Desc))
      .Field("_score", fs => fs.Order(SortOrder.Desc)))
```

```
var sortFields = new SortOptionsDescriptor<Model>()
            .Field(Infer.Field<Model>(f => f.rank_tx), fs => fs.Order(SortOrder.Desc))
            .Field("_score", fs => fs.Order(SortOrder.Desc));

.Sort(sortFields)
```

## Solution

There exists an overload of sort accepting a `params Action<SortOptionsDescriptor<TDocument>>[]`

```
var response = await _client.SearchAsync<Model>(search =>
{
    search.Index(_indexOptions.Index)
         .Query(q => q
            .Bool(b => b
                .Should(
                    sh => sh.MatchPhrasePrefix(m => m.Field(f => f.field1).Query(input)),
                    sh => sh.MatchPhrase(m => m.Field(f => f.field1).Query(input).Slop(50))
                )
            )
         )
        .Size(50)
        .Sort(
            s => s.Field(Infer.Field<Model>(f => f.rank_tx), fs => fs.Order(SortOrder.Desc)),
            s => s.Field("_score", fs => fs.Order(SortOrder.Desc)))
        .Highlight(highlightOptions);
}, cancellationToken);
```